# Can't create more team projects after update

Tags: tfs

After updated my TFS 2013 server to Update 4 i can't create anymore any team project inside visual studio. I receiving this error. I searched in entire network and already deleted my cache folder and changes xml agile file to false [Like says in this page.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88ec0bf2-676f-4ede-9895-9673346dbe30/error-message-when-creating-a-new-team-project-tf30323?forum=tfsgeneral)

[image: Error message after update]

Comment: The Team Explorer version must be aligned with the server, i.e. TE 2013 to create project in TFS 2013. Have you checked?

Comment: I have VS 2013 Update 4 installed and server have TFS2013.4

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Installed Version: Premium

Comment: If you have access to the TFS server itself you could try using the TFS Admin console to create the new Team Project. If it works then you know it's a client side issue, if not then you might get a better error message with more information

Comment: @pho3nix the plugin in the error is an assembly installed with Team Explorer. I would try repairing Visual Studio or from a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I downloaded C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Deploy\ProcessTemplateManagerFiles\1033\MsfAgile\Template.zip and unziped. In Xml file put all to false.

In my computer and in TFS Explorer > Settings > Process Manager Template Upload folder again and all works.